# Are Infinite ordinals and their successor equinumerous?

Tags: set-theory

Ordinals in set theory are well-ordered by $\in$ or equivalently $\subset$.
If we define all ordinals greater or equal to $\omega$ as infinite ordinals.
Is it true that every infinite ordinal is equinumerous to its successors.

Basically my question is the proof or refutation of the following statement:

Given infinite ordinal $\alpha$. Does there exist an injection from $\alpha^+$ to $\alpha$.

Comment: Use "Hilbert's Hotel". Map $x \mapsto x+1$ for $x \in \omega$, $\alpha \mapsto 0$ and everything else to itself.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply! This is a nice map. But is the Hilbert's Hotel only covers the countably many cases? What about ordinals like $\omega^+$ or $\omega^\omega$?

Comment: Just moving the members of $\omega$ gives you a "spare room" which you can put the new "guest" $\alpha$ into. The others can stay where they are, even if there are uncountably many of them.

Comment: Many thanks! I will have a look and think about it, not very familiar with that paradox at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  $$\alpha^+=\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$$ by definition.  Since $$\alpha\cap \{\alpha\}=\emptyset$$ we have $$|\alpha^+|=|\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}| =|\alpha|+|\{\alpha\}|=|\alpha|+1=|\alpha|
  $$ since $|\alpha|$ is infinite.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply!  How do we get the equivalence between cardinal arithmetic and ordinary arithmetic? Although this looks syntactically trivial, I cannot get the intuition behind it. I mean if a cardinal is an ordinal which is not equinumerous to its elements. The second equation means $\omega^+=\omega$ given $\alpha=\omega$ which is not the case in ordinal arithmetic. Also what is the definition for $|a\cup b|$ why it is equal to $|a|+|b|$?

Comment: @JoeYan I added some more detail.  Okay now?

Comment: Many thank for the quick reply! I cannot understand the derivation of $|a\cup b|=|a|+|b|$ given $a\cap b=\emptyset$. Yes, it is simple "numbering" by intuition such that if two sets have no common elements then the "size" of their union is the sum of their sizes. However, what if we follow strictly the definition that a cardinal is an ordinal which is not equinumerous to its elements and so the cardinality of a set is the cardinal equinumerous to it? This equation does not follows from formal set theory...

Comment: This is a basic fact of cardinal arithmetic.  Formal set theory wouldn't be much use if it didn't define addition of cardinal numbers!

Comment: If the addition of cardinal numbers is defined as follows: $a+b=|a\times \{0\} \cup b\times \{1\}|$. Then how does $|\alpha|+1=|\alpha|$ make sense. For example, $\omega + 1=\omega$?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Sorry, i miss typed enter and post comment unexpectedly, I have edited it

Comment: You are confusing cardinal arithmetic and ordinal arithmetic.  $\omega+1\neq\omega$, but $|\omega+1|=|\omega|$.

Comment: Many thanks for your patience! I agree with $|\omega +1|=|\omega|$ because infinite cardinals can only be limit ordinals. But what do you mean by $|\alpha|+1=|\alpha|$?

Comment: Do you believe that $\aleph_0+1=\aleph_0$?  That $\aleph_2+1=\aleph_2$?  That $\aleph_\omega+1=\aleph_\omega$?

Comment: If define $\aleph_0=\omega$ is a cardinal then $\aleph_0 +1$ is not a cardinal by definition because it is a successor ordinal (cardinals can only be limit ordinals).

Comment: This is pointless.  You need to read about cardinal arithmetic.

Comment: Arhh! Many thanks, I confused equality with equinumerous. For natural number $n$ and cardinal $\kappa$,$n+\kappa \cong(=) \kappa$ is true because there is a bijection $f(i,0)=i$ for all $i\in n$ and $f(\alpha,1)=n+\alpha$ for all $\alpha\in \kappa$. I accept your answer and great appreciation for your patience! Also, thanks to David Hartley's room idea remind me of the difference between equality and equinumerous. Sorry for my offence and nonsense.

Comment: @JoeYan No problem.